# Netbeans IDE 8.02 Java jFrame GUI bulder initComponents error

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

I am Currently building a GUI for a tic tak toe game and i have finished it all, however when I tried to run it failed so I checked the code to find the problem and the only one i can currently find is that initComponents is red lined and I am Having a hard time finding out why.

I am currently new to Java and have only started coding recently so any assistance in this will be very appreciated.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.Component;

/*
* To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
* To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/

/**
*
* @author matt
*/
 public class TicTacToe extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form TicTacToe
 */
public TicTacToe() {
    initComponents();
    addAction();
}

public void winEffect(JButton b1, JButton b2, JButton b3)
{
    b1.setBackground(Color.black);
    b2.setBackground(Color.black);
    b3.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    b1.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    b2.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    b3.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

    String msg = b1.getText()+ " Is the winner";
    jLabelMSG.setText(msg);
}
boolean win=false;
public void getthewinner(){

    if(jButton1.getText().equals("")&& jButton1.getText().equals(jButton2.getText())&& jButton1.getText().equals(jButton3.getText())){
        winEffect(jButton1, jButton2, jButton3);
        win=true;
}
       if(jButton4.getText().equals("")&& jButton4.getText().equals(jButton5.getText())&& jButton4.getText().equals(jButton6.getText())){
        winEffect(jButton4, jButton5, jButton6); 
       win=true;
       }
     if(jButton7.getText().equals("")&& jButton7.getText().equals(jButton8.getText())&& jButton7.getText().equals(jButton9.getText())){
        winEffect(jButton7, jButton8, jButton9);        
     win=true;
     }  
     if(jButton1.getText().equals("")&& jButton1.getText().equals(jButton4.getText())&& jButton1.getText().equals(jButton7.getText())){
        winEffect(jButton1, jButton4, jButton7);    
     win=true;
     }
     if(jButton2.getText().equals("")&& jButton2.getText().equals(jButton5.getText())&& jButton2.getText().equals(jButton9.getText())){
        winEffect(jButton2, jButton5, jButton8);      
     win=true;
     }
     if(jButton3.getText().equals("")&& jButton3.getText().equals(jButton6.getText())&& jButton3.getText().equals(jButton9.getText())){
winEffect(jButton3, jButton6, jButton9);       
     win=true;
     }

     if(jButton1.getText().equals("")&& jButton1.getText().equals(jButton5.getText())&& jButton1.getText().equals(jButton9.getText())){
winEffect(jButton1, jButton5, jButton9);          
     win=true;
     }
         if(jButton3.getText().equals("")&& jButton3.getText().equals(jButton5.getText())&&   jButton3.getText().equals(jButton7.getText())){
winEffect(jButton3, jButton5, jButton7);       
         win=true;
     }

     else if(allButtonTextLegnth()==9 && win==false){
         jLabelMSG.setText("no one wins");

     }
}    

public int allButtonTextLegnth(){

    String txt ="";

    Component[]comps= jPanel3.getComponents();   

    for(Component comp :comps){
        if(comp instanceof JButton){
        JButton button = (JButton)comp;
       txt = txt +button.getText();

    }

}
    return txt.length();

}
   int x_or_o =0;

public ActionListener createAction(JButton button){
    ActionListener al = new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(button.getText().equals("")){
                if((x_or_o %2)==0){
                    button.setText("x");
                    button.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
                    jLabelMSG.setText("o turn now");
                    getthewinner();
                }else{
                   button.setText("o");
                   button.setForeground(Color.red);
                   jLabelMSG.setText("x turn now");
                   getthewinner();
                }
                 x_or_o ++;
            }

}


};
    return al;
}

//function to add action to the buttons
public void addAction(){
    Component[]comps= jPanel3.getComponents();   

    for(Component comp :comps){
        if(comp instanceof JButton){
        JButton button = (JButton)comp;
        button.addActionListener(createAction(button));

    }

}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton5 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton6 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton7 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton8 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton9 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabelMSG = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jButtonReplay = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N

    jButton2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N

    jButton3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N

    jButton4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N

    jButton5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N

    jButton6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N

    jButton7.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N

    jButton8.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N

    jButton9.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N

    jPanel3.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 51, 51));

    jLabelMSG.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
    jLabelMSG.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    jLabelMSG.setText("jLabel1");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel3);
    jPanel3.setLayout(jPanel3Layout);
    jPanel3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(94, 94, 94)
            .addComponent(jLabelMSG)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(19, 19, 19)
            .addComponent(jLabelMSG)
            .addContainerGap(19, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    jButtonReplay.setText("replay");
    jButtonReplay.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButtonReplayActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(0, 80, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                        .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jButtonReplay, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 250, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addContainerGap())))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                        .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jButton7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 78, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                        .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 78, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jButton8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jButton5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jButton9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 74, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                                .addComponent(jButton6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 74, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 74, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGap(94, 94, 94))))))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 74, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 74, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 74, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 63, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 63, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 63, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jButton8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 64, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 64, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 64, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 30, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jButtonReplay)
            .addGap(24, 24, 24))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        
}
private void jButtonReplayActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              

    win =false;
    Component[]comps= jPanel3.getComponents();   

    for(Component comp :comps){
        if(comp instanceof JButton){
        JButton button = (JButton)comp;
        button.setText("");
        button.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        jLabelMSG.setText("play");

    }

}
}                                             

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TicTacToe.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        `enter code here`java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TicTacToe.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        `enter code here`java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TicTacToe.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {                                                            `enter code here`java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TicTacToe.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new TicTacToe().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton6;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton7;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton8;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton9;
private javax.swing.JButton jButtonReplay;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabelMSG;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

`

Comment: hover over the line with your mouse. normally it shows you whats wrong

Comment: This looks like you're missing a bracket or semi-colon.  For example, `addAction()` is missing a closing `}`, and also your class ends before `jButtonReplayActionPerformed` due to incorrect placement of another `}`.

Comment: @ XtremeBaumer  i looked over the top on at  public TicTacToe and that one said that it symbol is missing and the one at the bottom says that modifier private is not allowed

Comment: I copied into Eclipse, formatted it, and it seems you just have the `}` after `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` instead of before it. Also, remove the apostrophes and `enter code here` in the `try...catch` in `main`.

Comment: Not sure why this got an upvote; surely it should be closed due to typo or similar.

Comment: there is 1 `}` in the wrong place.

Comment: OK i removed the apostrophes and enter code here and I am try to find that } you mentioned, on what line is it?

Answer (score 0):

After your `initComponents` method, you have 2 closing `}` (after `pack()`).remove 1 of the brackets and add it after your `addAction()` method. this will solve your issue

Code with replaced class name:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.Component;

/*
* To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
* To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/

/**
 *
 * @author matt
 */
public class Test extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form TicTacToe
     */
    public Test() {
        initComponents();
        addAction();
    }

    public void winEffect(JButton b1, JButton b2, JButton b3) {
        b1.setBackground(Color.black);
        b2.setBackground(Color.black);
        b3.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        b1.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        b2.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        b3.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

        String msg = b1.getText() + " Is the winner";
        jLabelMSG.setText(msg);
    }

    boolean win = false;

    public void getthewinner() {

        if (jButton1.getText().equals("") && jButton1.getText().equals(jButton2.getText())
                && jButton1.getText().equals(jButton3.getText())) {
            winEffect(jButton1, jButton2, jButton3);
            win = true;
        }
        if (jButton4.getText().equals("") && jButton4.getText().equals(jButton5.getText())
                && jButton4.getText().equals(jButton6.getText())) {
            winEffect(jButton4, jButton5, jButton6);
            win = true;
        }
        if (jButton7.getText().equals("") && jButton7.getText().equals(jButton8.getText())
                && jButton7.getText().equals(jButton9.getText())) {
            winEffect(jButton7, jButton8, jButton9);
            win = true;
        }
        if (jButton1.getText().equals("") && jButton1.getText().equals(jButton4.getText())
                && jButton1.getText().equals(jButton7.getText())) {
            winEffect(jButton1, jButton4, jButton7);
            win = true;
        }
        if (jButton2.getText().equals("") && jButton2.getText().equals(jButton5.getText())
                && jButton2.getText().equals(jButton9.getText())) {
            winEffect(jButton2, jButton5, jButton8);
            win = true;
        }
        if (jButton3.getText().equals("") && jButton3.getText().equals(jButton6.getText())
                && jButton3.getText().equals(jButton9.getText())) {
            winEffect(jButton3, jButton6, jButton9);
            win = true;
        }

        if (jButton1.getText().equals("") && jButton1.getText().equals(jButton5.getText())
                && jButton1.getText().equals(jButton9.getText())) {
            winEffect(jButton1, jButton5, jButton9);
            win = true;
        }
        if (jButton3.getText().equals("") && jButton3.getText().equals(jButton5.getText())
                && jButton3.getText().equals(jButton7.getText())) {
            winEffect(jButton3, jButton5, jButton7);
            win = true;
        }

        else if (allButtonTextLegnth() == 9 && win == false) {
            jLabelMSG.setText("no one wins");

        }
    }

    public int allButtonTextLegnth() {

        String txt = "";

        Component[] comps = jPanel3.getComponents();

        for (Component comp : comps) {
            if (comp instanceof JButton) {
                JButton button = (JButton) comp;
                txt = txt + button.getText();

            }

        }
        return txt.length();

    }

    int x_or_o = 0;

    public ActionListener createAction(JButton button) {
        ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (button.getText().equals("")) {
                    if ((x_or_o % 2) == 0) {
                        button.setText("x");
                        button.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
                        jLabelMSG.setText("o turn now");
                        getthewinner();
                    } else {
                        button.setText("o");
                        button.setForeground(Color.red);
                        jLabelMSG.setText("x turn now");
                        getthewinner();
                    }
                    x_or_o++;
                }

            }

        };
        return al;
    }

    // function to add action to the buttons
    public void addAction() {
        Component[] comps = jPanel3.getComponents();

        for (Component comp : comps) {
            if (comp instanceof JButton) {
                JButton button = (JButton) comp;
                button.addActionListener(createAction(button));

            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton5 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton6 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton7 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton8 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton9 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabelMSG = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButtonReplay = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N

        jButton2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N

        jButton3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N

        jButton4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N

        jButton5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N

        jButton6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N

        jButton7.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N

        jButton8.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N

        jButton9.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N

        jPanel3.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 51, 51));

        jLabelMSG.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabelMSG.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabelMSG.setText("jLabel1");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel3);
        jPanel3.setLayout(jPanel3Layout);
        jPanel3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup().addGap(94, 94, 94).addComponent(jLabelMSG)
                        .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)));
        jPanel3Layout.setVerticalGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup().addGap(19, 19, 19).addComponent(jLabelMSG)
                        .addContainerGap(19, Short.MAX_VALUE)));

        jButtonReplay.setText("replay");
        jButtonReplay.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButtonReplayActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(layout
                .createSequentialGroup().addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(layout
                        .createSequentialGroup().addGap(0, 80, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                                .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING,
                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                        Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(jButtonReplay, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 250,
                                                javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addContainerGap())))
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup().addGroup(layout
                                .createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING,
                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                        Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(jButton7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 78, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                                        .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 78,
                                                Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                        .addComponent(jButton8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                                javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                        .addComponent(jButton5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                                javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                .addComponent(jButton9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 74,
                                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                                        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING,
                                                layout.createSequentialGroup().addGroup(layout
                                                        .createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING,
                                                                false)
                                                        .addComponent(jButton6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                                                74, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                        .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                                                74, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                                        .addGap(94, 94, 94)))))));
        layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 74,
                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 74,
                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 74,
                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 63,
                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(jButton6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 63,
                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(jButton5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 63,
                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(jButton8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 64,
                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(jButton7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 64,
                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(jButton9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 64,
                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 30, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jButtonReplay).addGap(24, 24, 24)));

        pack();
    }

    private void jButtonReplayActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

        win = false;
        Component[] comps = jPanel3.getComponents();

        for (Component comp : comps) {
            if (comp instanceof JButton) {
                JButton button = (JButton) comp;
                button.setText("");
                button.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                jLabelMSG.setText("play");

            }

        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     *            the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code
        // (optional) ">
        /*
         * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default
         * look and feel. For details see
         * http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        // </editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Test().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton6;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton7;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton8;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton9;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButtonReplay;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabelMSG;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```